# G722 Java or C++ impelementation

Tags: java, c++

I am developing a VoIP application and Need to know if there is any open-source implementation for G722 speech codecs. ?!

Comment: I need an example of using it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the g722 implementation from **jitsi** opensource internet phone which mainly based on **spanDSP**(C/C++) and jitsi call the native code using JNI.

libjitsi JNI:https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi/tree/master/src/net/java/sip/communicator/impl/neomedia/codec/audio/g722
Native code called from JNI: https://github.com/jitsi/libjitsi/tree/master/src/native/g722

There is 2 classes:
 
**JNIDecoder.java**: to decode raw PCM data from g722 bytes buffer
**JNIEncoder.java**: to encode raw PCM data into g722 bytes buffer

Answer (score 0):

Linform, I believe, is pretty cross-platform:

- http://www.linphone.org/

You might also want to look at OPAL:

- http://www.opalvoip.org/

Comment: Thanks , your answer give me a good push, here how i solved it :
I used the common g722 impl from spanDSP (all the working impl use it) and add JNI interface so i can use it in my JAVA App.